# Merging two landsat images

Tags: merge, saga, landsat

I have several Landsat 5 Images to merge together. As far as I saw from tutorials and previous questions there are two main methods (and none seem to be working for me):

1 - raster » miscelaneous » merge

2 - SAGA's Mosaic Rasters Layers

I just reinstalled Qgis 3.10 Coruna in Windows. All landsat images were obtained with the SCP pluggin

I made some screen shots to further explain:
These are the images I want to merge
[image: Image1 - band 3]
[image: Image2 - band3]

Method 1- Merge

I set the following parameters. I didn't forget to assign "0" as no data.

[image: Parameters for merging]

The end result was quite surprising. Not only it eliminated the overlapping pixels but also created this rectangular areas with a 0 value. Those areas are outside the limits of both images.

[image: Merged result]

Method 2 - SAGA's Mosaic Rasters Layers

I followed the parameters in one previous question:
[image: Saga Parameters]

but the results weren't generated
[image: Saga Log]

I confirmed: both images are in the same Datum. What can be the problem?

Comment: The error in the saga is probably due to spaces and accents in folder names. So much to copy to the root (D: /) and run again.

O erro no saga é provavelmente devido aos espaços e acentos nos nomes das pastas. Tanta copiar pra raiz(D:/) e executar novamente.

Comment: You are absolutly right. I run it in folders with simplier names, and it worked perfectly with SAGA

Answer (score 1):

The error in the saga is probably due to spaces and accents in folder names. So copy to the root (D: /) and run again.

Comment: Yes. That was the problem. Saga is now operational. What can be the problem with the GDAL tool, then?